# Anaconda - problem with removing environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

I tried to delete a conda environment that I no longer use. I had VSCode open, and even though that particular environment wasn't active within the terminal in VSCode, it seems that there was an issue with it being removed because I had VSCode open. The folder for the environment still appears in the envs folder within the Anaconda3 directory. When I run conda env list, the environment doesn't show up. However, I'm still able to activate it and see the packages installed for that env. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting VSCode?

Comment: … and/or your PC.  Although usually unnecessary, but there appears to be an unclosed file handle, which can present odd / unexpected behaviour.